# how to customize navigation menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress menu ,in that one item need to be inactive ,navigation to a particular page should not take place.A particular page has two sub items and navigation to the main menu item need to be inactive.I use wordpress 3.8.1 twenty fourteen theme ,and under menu I created a top level menu from pages ,One page is just for the menu purpose it has no content but has two submenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create it as a custom link with your current text as link text and `javascript:void(0);` as url

Comment: how to crete it as custom link

Comment: on the left side of menu you can see pages, links, categories